# Правильное получение связанной модели в Cycle ORM

Tags: php, orm, entity, repository

Возникла проблема:
На проекте используется Cycle ORM,имеется 2 Entity. Я пытаюсь связать их с помощью аннотации так:

```
    /**
 * @Cycle\Relation\BelongsTo(target = "Company\Core\Entity\CourtInfo\CourtInfo")
 */
protected $court;
```

Но при обращении к $repository->findOne()->getCourt() я получаю:

```
object(Cycle\ORM\Promise\Reference)#2212 (2) {
["role":"Cycle\ORM\Promise\Reference":private]=>
string(42) "Company\Core\Entity\CourtInfo\CourtInfo"
["scope":"Cycle\ORM\Promise\Reference":private]=>
array(1) {
["id"]=>
int(15705)
  }
}
```

Но хочу получить Entity. Как мне это правильно сделать?
Работает вариант, если добавить в параметры аннотации fetch="eager", но тогда будет грузиться жадно. Как мне лениво можно загрузить связанные сущности?

Answer (score 1):

В Cycle ORM v1  метод [ORM::get()](https://github.com/cycle/orm/blob/4f90d7cda5d8a1ab8a245e94c24394edf2e9a8d8/src/ORM.php#L126), в который передаются [role](https://github.com/cycle/orm/blob/4f90d7cda5d8a1ab8a245e94c24394edf2e9a8d8/src/Promise/Reference.php#L35) и [scope](https://github.com/cycle/orm/blob/4f90d7cda5d8a1ab8a245e94c24394edf2e9a8d8/src/Promise/Reference.php#L43) из Reference.

Автоматизировать этот процесс можно пакетом [cycle/proxy-factory](https://github.com/cycle/proxy-factory/). Однако, в этом случае могут возникнуть проблемы с nullable связями (при раскрытии Proxy не сможет превратить себя в null).

В Cycle ORM v2 эти сложности устранены: достаточно использовать маппер по умолчанию и ленивые связи будут сами раскрываться при обращении к ним.